# Comparing date and timestamp with BETWEEN clause

Tags: oracle

The basic structure of my query is this:

```
SELECT....FROM....
WHERE SYSTIMESTAMP BETWEEN DateA and DateB.
```

I am trying various ways, one of them is, but getting errors like
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string OR in some cases 'not a valid month'

```
WHERE
SYSTIMESTAMP BETWEEN 
      TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE(DateA,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),  'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SSFF') AND 
      TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE(DateB,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),  'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SSFF')
```

DateA and DateB columns are of type DATE and SYSTIMESTAMP is obviously TIMESTAMP.

NLS settings on my SQL developer are

- For Date: `'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'`
- For TIMESTAMP: `'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'`

Please help me in identifying the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TO_TIMESTAMP` and `TO_DATE` both take a string and convert it to a timestamp/date respectively using the specified format mask.

Therefore doing `TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE(..)...)` doesn't make sense - especially when your original column is already in a date format! You need one or the other.

By doing `TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE(<date_column>..)...)`, what you're doing is forcing oracle to do some implicit conversions from a date into a string and back to a date then back to a string, so that it can be converted back into a timestamp. That looks something like this:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(<date_column>, <nls_date_format>), <your_date_format>), <nls_date_format>), <your_timestamp_format>).
```

That's massively overcomplicated, right? Plus, if one of those formats doesn't match, then you'll get the errors you're experiencing.

If you want to convert a DATE into a TIMESTAMP, you can use CAST, e.g.:

```
where systimestamp between cast(datea as timestamp) and cast(dateb as timestamp)
```

or you can let Oracle handle the implicit conversion from the date into a timestamp and just do:

```
where systimestamp between datea and dateb
```

or simply avoid the issue altogether by using sysdate instead of systimestamp, i.e.:

```
where sysdate between datea and dateb
```

Comment: Thanks to you and others for providing the answers. I am relatively new to Oracle (previously worked on other db tools), so sometimes I am really confused when it comes to date related operations.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a conversion to check a `timestamp` against a `date`; for example:

```
SQL> desc testDate
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DATEA                                              DATE
 DATEB                                              DATE

SQL> select * from testDate;

DATEA     DATEB
--------- ---------
21-MAY-17 23-MAY-17
19-MAY-17 21-MAY-17

SQL> select *
  2  from testDate
  3  where systimestamp between dateA and dateB ;

DATEA     DATEB
--------- ---------
21-MAY-17 23-MAY-17

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert to a timestamp if you already have it in the DATE format. Just use:

```
WHERE SYSTIMESTAMP BETWEEN DateA AND DateB
```

Comment: ... but should not post the same answer twice, IMHO